# Create an empty multidimensional array of a union type in Julia

Tags: arrays, types, julia, union-types

Using Julia, I'm trying to initialize an empty array of type `Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, Date, DateTime, Time, String}` for working with Excel files. I tried `zeros(Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, Date, DateTime, Time, String}, rows, cols)`, but that didn't work since `zeros` has no such attribute. I also tried `Array{Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, Date, DateTime, Time, String}, rows, cols}`, but that returned a type rather than an empty array. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick way

```
julia> a = Array{Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, String},1}(missing,3)
3-element Array{Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, String},1}:
 missing
 missing
 missing

julia> a[2] = 5
5

julia> a
3-element Array{Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, String},1}:
  missing
 5
  missing
```

And if you need a 2D array, you can do this

```
julia> a = Array{Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, String},2}(missing,3,4)
3×4 Array{Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, String},2}:
 missing  missing  missing  missing
 missing  missing  missing  missing
 missing  missing  missing  missing

julia> a[2,3]=5
5

julia> a
3×4 Array{Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, String},2}:
 missing  missing   missing  missing
 missing  missing  5         missing
 missing  missing   missing  missing
```

To describe an EXCEL spreadsheet, "missing" may not be the appropriate word, "nothing" may be better.

```
julia> a = Array{Union{Nothing, Bool, Float64, Int64, String},2}(nothing,3,4)
3×4 Array{Union{Nothing, Bool, Float64, Int64, String},2}:
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
 nothing  nothing  nothing  nothing
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me why "Date" and "DateTime" does not work? I tried them but I keep getting this error message. ERROR: UndefVarError: Date not defined and ERROR: UndefVarError: DateTime not defined

Comment: Maybe because you are using Julia 1.0, where they are put into a standard library. Try `using Dates`.

Comment: You can also use `undef` instead of `missing` or `nothing`, and you'll get undefined entries. It's slightly faster, but an error will be throw if you try to access an undefined entry.

Comment: @StevenSiew Your answer was helpful to me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Collating the previous answers and comments gives in Julia 1.0.0:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> a = Array{Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, Date, DateTime, Time, String}, 1}(undef, 3)
3-element Array{Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, Date, DateTime, Time, String},1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef

julia> a[1] = today()
2018-09-30

julia> a[2] = julian2datetime(2437500)
1961-07-19T12:00:00

julia> a[3] = "this is a test string"
"this is a test string"

julia> a
3-element Array{Union{Missing, Bool, Float64, Int64, Date, DateTime, Time, String},1}:
 2018-09-30
 1961-07-19T12:00:00
 "this is a test string"
```